# How to sort a List on the fly as fast as possible

Tags: c#

I am looking for a way to sort a List as fast as possible as this will happen trillions of times.

The loop generates decimal values and then the string will be put into a "sortedLIST". Here I want the lowest decimal value to be at top of the list and the highest decimal value at the bottom of the list.

In this scenario. How can we do this as fast as possible?

Thank you!

```
void sortfunction()
{
    //The decimal values will actually dynamically be calculated in this loop in reality
    List<String> sortedLIST = new List<String>();
    Random random = new Random(); 
    double rand = 0; 
    double num = 0; 
    String str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
    {
        rand = random.Next(0, 99);
        num = rand / 100;
        str = num + "|hello1|hello2|hello3";

        //Is it possible to sort the values on the FLY here directly somehow with the LOWEST at the top. 
        //So insert them at the correct index right away somehow or if there is faster approach?
        sortedLIST.Add(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother adding the number as a string with a suffix? Just store the numbers and add the suffix when you get the numbers out. This will save a huge amount of memory.

Comment: Using a SortedList<int, string> would solve the problem of sorting on-the-fly but cannot promise to be the fastest way.

Comment: Why is this happening "trillions of times"? Why not explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Just fill the list as you're doing, but quicksort it at the end.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why don't you post your actual code?

Comment: `Random.Next` returns an integer. You could achieve exactly the same result just by counting each result from 0 to 98, then generating the strings in order (if you even need them) at the end.

Comment: @Sean. The real world example would be exactly as my example. There is no way around it I am afraid.

Comment: Why do you need to sort after each insertion? (and not at the end)

Comment: @Magnus, I am just thinking if there is a way to do it on-the-fly that could make it faster. It is just an idéa. Perheps that is not possible. I am not sure yet.

Comment: The fastest you can do with "on the fly" would be to use some kind of binary tree structure and that would cost you O(log n) for every insertion. Sorting at the end would be O(n log n).

Comment: Realizing the number of items (str) you are producing, you probably want to use `rand = random.NextDouble() * 100d;` which will give you a double between 0 and 100 (exclusive).  Because as-is, you will have around 5000 str's for each value 0.00, 0.01, 0.02, . . . , 0.98 (the 99 in the Next() is exclusive) in your collection. Am I right?

Comment: And since you are dividing this by 100 right afterward, just `num = random.NextDouble();` maybe? (makes rand redundant)

Comment: @Oguz The random function is just an example. The real numbers come from an actual other calculation. It is just for demonstrating the example.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, you don't need to add the string prefix to every item, you can just add it when you take something out of the list. This means you can store the list as a list of `int` rather than `string`.

As you know the number of items you are creating you can pre-size the list when creating it to avoid reallocations when populating it. Once it's populated you can call [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8) which swithces between quick sort, heap sort and insertion sort depending on the number of items in the list.

Here's the code:

```
void sortfunction()
{
    const int numberOfItems = 500000;

    var sortedList = new List<double>(numberOfItems);
    Random random = new Random(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        var rand = random.Next(0, 99);
        var num = rand / 100d;

        sortedList.Add(num);
    }

    sortedList.Sort();
}
```

Comment: List of double.

Comment: Yes the `const int numberOfItems = 500000;` was a good idéa to use there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using System.Linq you can quickly sort a List through the use of [OrderBy(IEnumerable, Func)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) . It is quick, especially whenit comes to int or string comparisons.

```
List.OrderBy(a=> a);
```

Comment: It is not as fast (once the resulting `IEnumerable<>` is actually "consumed", i.e. enumerated) as sorting the `List<>` in place, with `list.Sort();`.

Comment: `List.OrderBy(a=> a);` doesn't seem to sort the list. The decimal values appears on random?

Comment: @Andreas You need to assign it back as `List = List.OrderBy(a=>a).ToList();`

Comment: @Andreas, when you use `OrderBy` the sorting is not done in place, but is returned as a result of the operation (new collection)

Comment: @ironstone, I made a benchmark. So far the .Sort() is faster: `sortedLIST = sortedLIST.OrderBy(a => a).ToList()` took 8.45 seconds and `sortedLIST.Sort()` took 5.6 seconds

Comment: @Andreas - you need a faster machine. `sortedList.Sort()` took 1.7 seconds on mine, in debug mode!

Comment: @Sean wow how could it take 1.7 seconds only? What processor do you have. I have a supercomputer with 24 cores. But each core is 2.2 GHZ.

Comment: @Andreas - each core of mine is 3.9 Ghz.

Comment: @Sean that is really fast cores. Perheps that is the reason. I use many cores as I will run everything i parallell later on to make it faster that way instead. But my cores are a bit slower than normal I beleive.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion with a Merge Sort algorithm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Merge_sort
{    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> unsorted = new List<int>();
            List<int> sorted;

            Random random = new Random();

            Console.WriteLine("Original array elements:" );
            for(int i = 0; i< 10;i++){
                unsorted.Add(random.Next(0,100));
                Console.Write(unsorted[i]+" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            sorted = MergeSort(unsorted);

            Console.WriteLine("Sorted array elements: ");
            foreach (int x in sorted)
            {
                Console.Write(x+" ");
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }


        private static List<int> MergeSort(List<int> unsorted)
        {
            if (unsorted.Count <= 1)
                return unsorted;

            List<int> left = new List<int>();
            List<int> right = new List<int>();

            int middle = unsorted.Count / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < middle;i++)  //Dividing the unsorted list
            {
                left.Add(unsorted[i]);
            }
            for (int i = middle; i < unsorted.Count; i++)
            {
                right.Add(unsorted[i]);
            }

            left = MergeSort(left);
            right = MergeSort(right);
            return Merge(left, right);
        }

        private static List<int> Merge(List<int> left, List<int> right)
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();

            while(left.Count > 0 || right.Count>0)
            {
                if (left.Count > 0 && right.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (left.First() <= right.First())  //Comparing First two elements to see which is smaller
                    {
                        result.Add(left.First());
                        left.Remove(left.First());      //Rest of the list minus the first element
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(right.First());
                        right.Remove(right.First());
                    }
                }
                else if(left.Count>0)
                {
                    result.Add(left.First());
                    left.Remove(left.First());
                }
                else if (right.Count > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(right.First());

                    right.Remove(right.First());    
                }    
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

> source:
>   https://www.w3resource.com/csharp-exercises/searching-and-sorting-algorithm/searching-and-sorting-algorithm-exercise-7.php